# Invalid template file when installing theme

Tags: magento2, theme, design

I have installed a theme into my Magento store and now I want to try to switch to that theme. After installing and setting the them in the configuration through the admin panel, I get the following error when I try to visit the store:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: '/bitnami/magento/htdocs/app/design/frontend/Bege/bege1/Magento_Theme/templates/page/js/require_js.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'require.js'

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: '/bitnami/magento/htdocs/app/design/frontend/Bege/bege1/Magento_Theme/templates/page/js/require_js.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'require.js'
#0 /opt/bitnami/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(300): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/bitnami/magent...')
#1 /opt/bitnami/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(667): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#2 /opt/bitnami/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(248): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#3 /opt/bitnami/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(170): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#4 /opt/bitnami/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#5 /opt/bitnami/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', Array)
#6 /opt/bitnami/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#7 /opt/bitnami/magento/htdocs/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)
#8 /opt/bitnami/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(139): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#9 /opt/bitnami/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#10 /opt/bitnami/magento/htdocs/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#11 {main}
```

I already checked permission, path and they both seems to be correct.
The content of require_js.phtm is as follow:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
?>
<script>
    var require = {
        "baseUrl": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getViewFileUrl('/'); ?>"
    };
</script>
```

It seems valid php to me.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code its working for me :

`vendor/magento/framework/view/element/template/file/validator.php` with this.

```
protected function isPathInDirectories($path, $directories)
{
    $realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
    if (!is_array($directories)) {
        $directories = (array)$directories;
    }

    foreach ($directories as $directory) {
        if (0 === strpos($realPath, $directory)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

and than now reload the magento application.

**hope its work for you**